# escaping pipe ("|") in a regex

Tags: regex, r

I have a need to split on words and end marks (punctuation of certain types).  Oddly pipe ("|") can count as an end mark.  I have code that words on end marks until I try to add the pipe.  Adding the pipe makes the `strsplit` every character.  Escaping it causes and error.  How can I include the pipe int he regular expression?

```
x <- "I like the dog|."

strsplit(x, "[[:space:]]|(?=[.!?*-])", perl=TRUE)
#[[1]]
#[1] "I"    "like" "the"  "dog|" "."   

strsplit(x, "[[:space:]]|(?=[.!?*-\|])", perl=TRUE)
#Error: '\|' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "[[:space:]]|(?=[.!?*-\|"
```

The outcome I'd like:

```
#[[1]]
#[1] "I"    "like" "the"  "dog"  "|"  "."  #pipe is an element
```

Comment: I am always hesitant to put regex tags on R regex questions because you get regexers from other languages and though the answers are similar they don't overlap.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One way to solve this is to use the `\Q...\E` notation to remove the special meaning of any of the characters in `...`.  As it says in `?regex`:

> If you want to remove the special meaning from a sequence of 
>   characters, you can do so by putting them between ‘\Q’ and ‘\E’.  This
>   is different from Perl in that ‘$’ and ‘@’ are handled as  literals in
>   ‘\Q...\E’ sequences in PCRE, whereas in Perl, ‘$’ and  ‘@’ cause
>   variable interpolation.

For example:

```
> strsplit(x, "[[:space:]]|(?=[\\Q.!?*-|\\E])", perl=TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] "I"    "like" "the"  "dog"  "|"    "."
```

Comment: Interesting. I definitely need to read up on regex some more. +1

Comment: @Joshua, mrdwab gave a great answer and this is even more thorough.  I never even heard of the `\\Q ... \\E` thing.  very useful information.

Comment: @TylerRinker: I'd never heard of it either, until I read the documentation after seeing your question. ;-)

Comment: @Joshua, you're going to make a statement like that and not provide the link :P

Comment: @TylerRinker: As I said in my answer, it's in `?regex`, see the *Perl-like Regular Expressions* section.

Comment: There it is.  Thank you +1 for comment.

Answer (score 12):

The problem is actually your hyphen, which should come either [first or last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589074/regex-should-hyphens-be-escaped):

```
strsplit(x, "[[:space:]]|(?=[|.!?*-])", perl=TRUE)
strsplit(x, "[[:space:]]|(?=[.|!?*-])", perl=TRUE)
strsplit(x, "[[:space:]]|(?=[.!|?*-])", perl=TRUE)
strsplit(x, "[[:space:]]|(?=[-|.!?*])", perl=TRUE)
```

and so on should all give you the output you are looking for.

You can also escape the hyphen if you prefer, but remember to use two backslashes!

```
strsplit(x, "[[:space:]]|(?=[.!?*\\-|])", perl=TRUE)
```

Comment: Both excellent answers, josh gave even more detail.  Thank you for your answer +1