# Why is this Java regex not matching my string?

Tags: java, regex

I have the following Java code:

```
String data = "MaxL-450";

if(!data.matches("MaxL\\-*"))
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Did not match.");
```

When I execute it, the exception is thrown, because apparently the regex doesn't match my `data` string. Is there something wrong with my regex or is something else going on here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know why everybody is using \\ here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @DaveNewton - what would you use instead of \\?

Comment: One slash do escape the next character (for the regex) and another slash to escape the slash (for Java).

Comment: Ahhh gotchya - hyphen is apparently an escape character, which is why I put it in there.

Comment: @DirtyMikeAndTheBoys Hyphens have meaning in ranges; outside of a range I don't see why it needs to be escaped.

Comment: My issue with "\\-" is that the "\\" isn't necessary, and IMO it leads to a bit of cargo-cult programming. Hyphens don't need to be escaped if they're not in a character range, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589074/regex-should-hyphens-be-escaped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`*` means zero or more occurrences of the previous character. You want something like `"MaxL-[0-9]*"`, assuming you want to match a number after the dash.

Alternatively you could use `"MaxL-\\d*"`. Note that you need two slashes in Java, since you need to escape the slash itself. Personally I like using explicit character classes (i.e. `[0-9]`) in Java, as its slightly easier to read as your regex inevitably gets longer and more complex.

Edit: Also, as Dave Newton points out, the escape slashes in front of the dash aren't necessary as the dash isn't inside a character class.

Comment: You could use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`.

Comment: Thanks @Zutty (+1) - so would `MaxL\\-\d+` match against 1+ occurrences of any number? When I use that I get a compiler error...

Comment: Thanks again @Zutty - but I tried that and getting the following error: `Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )`... any ideas?

Comment: My issue with "\\-" is that the "\\" isn't necessary, and IMO it leads to a bit of cargo-cult programming. Hyphens don't need to be escaped if they're not in a character range, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589074/regex-should-hyphens-be-escaped.

Comment: Good point. Made another edit. It was just laziness on my part, but I shouldn't promote poor coding practice.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for ANY chars after the hyphen:

```
if(!data.matches("MaxL\\-.*"))
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Did not match.");
```