# How to add a dash to pattern matching

Tags: sql-server

This works:

```
select Name
from Table
WHERE Name like '%[^0-9A-Za-z]%'
```

But now I need to add the dash character to the criteria as well.

Answer (score 16):

use

```
...ESCAPE '\'
```

e.g.

```
WHERE Name like '%[^0-9A-Za-z\-]%' ESCAPE '\'
```

to have the final "-" treated as a literal.

Comment: There is some interesting discussion on escaping [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589074/regex-should-hyphens-be-escaped).

Answer (score 8):

Unless it's part of a range the hyphen is not a special character in `LIKE` patterns, so you can just add it to your pattern, e.g.:

```
select 
        [char]
from
    (
    select 'a' as 'char' union 
    select '-' union 
    select '$' union
    select '7'
    ) dt
where 
    [char] like '%[^A-Za-z0-9-]%'
```

Comment: Wording this lightly differently, unless the hyphen is the first or last character in the set then it *defines* a range so for it to be treated literally it must be the first or last character.

Comment: Comment from Rhys Jones is critical, [^A-Za-z0-9-_] would fail

Comment: Not to argue this is wrong, but strangely I just came across one use case where `not like '%[^A-Za-z0-9-]%'` did not work as intended, but `not like '%[^A-Za-z0-9\-]%' escape '\'` did. Curious about why