# Regex trying to match characters before and after symbol

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match characters before and after a symbol, in a string.

string: `budgets-closed`

To match the characters before the sign `-`, I do: `^[a-z]+`

And to match the other characters, I try: `\-(\w+)` but, the problem is that my result is: `-closed` instead of `closed`.

Any ideas, how to fix it?

### Update

This is the piece of code, where I was trying to apply the regex http://jsfiddle.net/trDFh/1/

I repeat: It's not that I don't want to use split; it's just I was really curious, and wanted to see, how can it be done the regex way. Hacking into things spirit

### Update2

Well, using `substring` is a solution as well: http://jsfiddle.net/trDFh/2/ and is the one I chosed to use, since the if in question, is actually an `else if` in a more complex `if` syntax, and the chosen solutions seems to be the most fitted for now.

Comment: @Floris testing it with regexpal, and it doesn't work

Comment: There is no lookbehind support in JS.

Comment: When you say "trying to match characters" - what would you like the output to be?

Comment: @floris well... I'm trying to have `budgets` and `closed` without using split.

Comment: I gave you a solution for that type of string, without regexp grouping or split. Is it what you need?

Comment: "trying to have" - in separate variables? in the same variable? Could you write a short piece of code that has "and here a miracle happens" as one of the steps? Some of the solutions proposed seem quite legitimate but you don't like them - trying to figure out why not.

Comment: I've posted a link to a jsfiddle. Thank you folks for the help! I posted this question out of the curiosity of learning and see if someone could bring a solution to my poor regex language knowledge. I guess I will use `split`

Comment: @w0rldart your update 2 kind of contradicts your first update...

Comment: Here's how you could do it without regex at all: http://jsfiddle.net/thetenfold/trDFh/3/

Comment: source = '/panel/' + remote.match(/^[a-z]+(?=\-)/g) + '/data/' + remote.match(/(?!\-)(\w+)$/g);

Comment: @JoeSimmons interesting, but I'd rather use `.replace` and convert `budgets-closed` to `budgets/closed`.

Comment: Hey, it's your code. Do what you need :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec):

```
var result=/([^-]+)-([^-]+)/.exec(string);
```

`result` is an array, with `result[1]` being the first captured string and `result[2]` being the second captured string.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Pqntk/

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll have to match that. You can use grouping to get what you need, though.

```
var str = 'budgets-closed';
var matches = str.match( /([a-z]+)-([a-z]+)/ );

var before = matches[1];
var after = matches[2];
```

---

For that specific string, you could also use

```
var str = 'budgets-closed';
var before = str.match( /^\b[a-z]+/ )[0];
var after = str.match( /\b[a-z]+$/ )[0];
```

---

I'm sure there are better ways, but the above methods do work.

Comment: Same thing as a split, and I don't want that. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Ok, well, you don't have any other ways of doing it. Sorry.

Comment: @w0rldart Why isn't `split` a valid solution?

Comment: @elclanrs it's not that it isn't a valid solution, it just I was hopping of "hacking" into this issue, by using regex. split, would've been my last resort.

Comment: I updated my answer. There is a way to get what you want for that specific type of string.

Answer (score 0):

If the symbol is specifically `-`, then this should work:

```
\b([^-]+)-([^-]+)\b
```

You match a boundry, any "not `-`" characters, a `-` and then more  "not `-`" characters until the next word boundry.

Also, there is no need to escape a hyphen, it only holds [special properties when between two other characters inside a character class.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589074/regex-should-hyphens-be-escaped)

edit: And here is a [jsfiddle that demonstrates it *does work*](http://jsfiddle.net/3nRka/).

Comment: well, the thing is that your proposed solution... it doesn't work. I gave it a quick try using regexpal

Comment: Oh, I see.. was testing it in a different way.

Comment: @w0rldart regexpal matches the entire pattern, and doesn't show you the grouping within the regex. I'd recommend [rubular](http://rubular.com/) instead. (Fun fact, almost all regexes in all languages use the same PREL syntax).

Comment: Yea, I had figure it out after testing at regexpal, that your regex matches the whole string. Nice touch