# how to allow hyphens using regex

Tags: java, regex, struts

I want the user to enter hyphens with the following code

```
<var>
    <var-name>mask</var-name>
    <var-value>^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$</var-value>
</var>
```

I am using struts validation. so please help me to address this.

**EDIT**

the user can enter the hyphens anywhere in the string,so there is no restriction on whether the `-` should be at the beginning, middle or end.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex - Should hyphens be escaped?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589074/regex-should-hyphens-be-escaped)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should escape it as follows:

```
<var>
    <var-name>mask</var-name>
    <var-value>^[a-zA-Z0-9\-]*$</var-value>
</var>
```

This is because `-` is a special construct in regex and therefore if you want to treat it literally, escape it.

Comment: @sshashank124: Be careful, `\w` also matches `_` as it's a shorthand for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Also, escaping the `-` is unnecessary when at the very beginning or end of the character class.

Answer (score 6):

`-` is a special character inside a character class, you can 'escape' it by putting it at the beginning or the end:

```
[-a-zA-Z0-9]
```

This character class will match one character, either:

- a hyphen `-`
- or a letter (upper or lowercase)
- or a digit

When you use it that way: `^[-a-zA-Z0-9]*$`, you ensure that your string is composed only by these characters (no restriction on the position of the hyphen or the other possible characters)

Comment: @Edan: Please see mine, I think you are confused about the character class role itself.