# Regexp for checking a-z‚ A-Z‚ 0-9, -, _, but no more than 5 numbers

Tags: php, regex

Can someone tell me what the syntax for a regex would be that would only allow the following characters:

```
a-z 
A-Z
0-9
dash
underscore
```

Additionally the string cannot contain more than 5 numbers.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: `\w` covers `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` use `[\w-]`. Now the next point is 5 numbers that is difficult to achieve using regex but possible.

Comment: extract all the digits from string using `\d` regex pattern and check the count.

Comment: `^(?!(.*\d){6})[-\w]*$` - Uses a negative lookahead to prevent more than 5 numbers.

Comment: How does that meet your requirements @olehan? It doesn't hold up under testing. Can you provide an example of what you want to match as well as what shouldn't match?

Answer (score 1):

The regex you need is

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{0,5}$
```

It matches any combination of the characters up to five characters.

Comment: [Hyphens Escaped?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589074/regex-should-hyphens-be-escaped) @Braj

Comment: And I am not sure the OP specified their requirements properly @Braj. If you look at the comments above you'll see another regex that "doesn't work" against the "requirements". Seems we're all guessing here.

Answer (score 0):

several possibilities:

```
~\A(?:[a-z_-]*[0-9]){0,5}[a-z_-]*\z(?<=.)~i
```

or

```
~\A(?!(?:.*[0-9]){6})[\w-]+\z~
```

The two patterns assumes that the empty string is not allowed.

First pattern:

```
~                        # pattern delimiter
\A                       # anchor for the start of the string
(?:[a-z_-]*[0-9]){0,5}   # repeat this group between 0 or 5 times (so 5 digits max)
[a-z_-]*                 # zero or more allowed characters
\z                       # end of the string
(?<=.)                   # lookbehind that checks there is at least one character
~
i                        # make the pattern case insensitive
```

second pattern:

```
~
\A
(?!                  # negative lookahead that checks there is not
    (?:.*[0-9]){6}   # 6 digits in the string
)  
[\w-]+
\z
~
```