# jQuery split with multiple argument

Tags: jquery, regex

I want to split my following string with multiple argument like `space and / and :`

```
21-10-2015 / 7:49:43 AM
```

I tried following Regular Expression

```
str.split(/[:-\/]/)
----------^
```

But it give me error like `SyntaxError: invalid range in character class` how to resolve it  ?

Comment: You need to escape the hyphen, `\-`, which normally indicates a range of characters, for example `a-z` or `0-9`.

Comment: `"21-10-2015 / 7:49:43 AM".split(/[\s/:]+/)` and Why are you using `-` in regex when don't intent to split using it?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Regex - Should hyphens be escaped?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589074/regex-should-hyphens-be-escaped)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because you're including the hypen as the second character in the Regex which is making the parser believe you're trying to set a range between `:` and `\` - which cannot be made. Place the `-` first in the set, or escape it. To include a space in the characters, add `\s` to the Regex.

```
str.split(/[-:\/\s]/);
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/sq7fLjhm/1/)

Comment: Your expression working fine but I also want to split with `space`. Pls help me

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan `Place the - first in the set` or `last`.