# how to check the regex allow hyphen or not?

Tags: java, regex

how to differentiate hyphen in the following regex
[a-zA-Z-0-9%-+-()]+ 
which denotes range and which denotes symbol

Comment: You can use hyphens in java regex classes. Just use it as the last character. Alternatively, escape it: `[\\-]`.

Comment: I want to differentiate hyphens.For example in [a-z-0-9]+ first hyphen denotes range second hyphen denotes symbol(-) third denotes range.

Comment: Actually, all these work: `"[-a-z0-9]+"`, `"[a-z0-9-]+"`, `"[a-z\\-0-9]+"`, and `"[a-z-0-9]+"`. That surprised me. I had expected the 4th one to throw an error, and I would suggest not using it.

Answer (score 0):

See [Regex - Should hyphens be escaped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589074/regex-should-hyphens-be-escaped)

Because the hyphen is a special character, you have to escape it using the backward slash otherwise it will, as you suggested, denote a range.

Include `\-` to find a hyphen. If you want to match an entire string if it has a hyphen use `.*\-.*`, if you want...the possibilities are endless.

You can use this site for quick testing of your regex patterns: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: [a-zA-Z-0-9]+  If the given regex allow - .Then how can i differentiate that hyphen.

Comment: You don't escape using the forward slash (`/`), you escape using the backward slash (``\``). And you only need to escape inside a character class, so `.*-.*` works just file without escaping.

Comment: the hyphen between two ranges should be considered as a symbol          [a-z-0-9]+ we don't need to escape it

Comment: Andreas is correct, I used a backward slash but wrote forward. Corrected my comment.