# Regular expression search not working when changing the order of pattern

Tags: python, regex

I am just writing a small regex to filter email from string. When I am using pattern as `patt = r'[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+'`, it's working fine. But when I am using pattern as `patt1 = r'[\w-.]+@[\w-.]+'`, its giving me error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 146, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 251, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: bad character range
```

Code:

1st case:

```
>>> str = "hello@abc.com"
>>> patt = r'[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+'
>>> match = re.search(patt, str)
>>> match.group()
'hello@abc.com'
```

2nd case:

```
>>> str = "hello@abc.com"
>>> patt = r'[\w-.]+@[\w-.]+'
>>> match = re.search(patt, str)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 146, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 251, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: bad character range
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong in the second regex?

Comment: Problem is probably because of the hyphen present inside `\w-` character class, so python interprets it as a character interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hyphens `-` need to be the first or last in the list. They have special meaning when used between two characters to indicate a range, like `[A-Z]` (all uppercase letters). When a hyphen is at the end or beginning, it has not special meaning.

Also, escaping it `\-` will work in Python, but beware it may not in other implementations/languages.

Check out the accepted answer here: [Regex - Should hyphens be escaped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589074/regex-should-hyphens-be-escaped)

Not the exact same question as yours, but touches on similar information.

Answer (score 1):

The dash (`-`) inside a character class (`[]`) indicates a character range i.e. *from-to*. So, if you want to use literal `-`, you have 3 options:

- put `-` at the start: `[-foo]`
- put `-` at the end: `[foo-]`
- escape `-` with `\`: `[foo\-bar]`