# Operator precedence and ternary operator

Tags: c, operator-precedence, ternary

I have a problem in C.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a = 10, b = 0, c = 7;
    if (a ? b : c == 0)
        printf("1");
    else if (c = c || a && b)
        printf("2");
    return 0;
}
```

This code prints 2 but I think a?b:c returns b=0 and 0==0 returns 1. Can you explain the code?

Comment: Why don't you just look up the operator precedence table? Such kinds of questions are useless otherwise.

Comment: If you know this is about precedence, why don't use the [precedence order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence) to figure out where to put parentheses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your conditions are not properly written.

In the first if-statement:

```
  if (a ? b : c == 0)
```

if you put the values, then it becomes

```
if(10 ? 0 : 7 == 0)
```

means, it will always return 0.

That's why control goes to the else part and there, it becomes

```
else if (7 = 7 || 10 && 0)
```

since you used the "=" operator here (c = c), it will be always true, therefore it prints "2".

Now you want that code should return "1", then change your if statement in this way.

```
 if( (a ? b:c) == 0){...}
```

because "==" operator has higher precedence than ternary operator.

Answer (score 9):

The conditional operator (`?:`) has one of the lowest precedences. In particular it is lower than `==`. Your statement means this:

```
if(a ? b : (c == 0)) { ... }
```

Not this:

```
if((a ? b : c) == 0) { ... }
```