# Equivalent to Lua "and/or" in C++?

Tags: c++, lua

In Lua, you can do this:

```
foo = a and b or c and d or e
```

Which is equivalent to (at least I am pretty sure it is equivalent to):

```
local foo = nil
if a then
foo = b
elseif c then
foo = d
else
foo = e
end
```

Is there anything equivalent or similar to this in C++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation#C.2C_Java.2C_JavaScript).  It has funny precedence, so it's good practice to always parenthesize it.

```
bool foo = ( a ? b : ( c ? d : e ) )
```

Note that this only works if `b`, `d`, and `e` can reduce to the same type.  If `a` is a `double`, `d` is a `float` and `e` is an `int`, your result will always be cast to a `double`.

Comment: What's funny about `?:`'s precedence? It's lower than any non-assigning operator and higher than all assigning ones, and that's it. So you can easily leave out the outer parentheses. What's somewhat more funny is its _associativity_, that's why you need parens between nested `?:`s.

Comment: @leftaroundabout it doesn't have the precedence I would expect it to have.  Example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10007140/382471

Comment: The precedence is quite reasonable: it makes sense to write stuff like `foo =  c=='x' ? x : y` or `foo =  a||b ? x : y`, so it's got to have lower precedence than the logical- and comparison operators. — Also, I need to take back what I said about associativity: it's simply right-associative, so you can leave out the inner parens as well. Though you should spread the expression over three lines with suitable indentation then, otherwise it becomes unreadable.

Answer (score 6):

I guess this is what you want:

```
foo = a ? b : (c ? d : e );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ternary operator `?:`

```
foo = a ? b : c ? d : e;
```

Comment: while it's not necessary to add brackets here, I would do so anyway to improve clarity -- the above code is just about readable with a bunch of single-letter variable names, but anything more complex than the example given would quickly become unmanageable.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. The main reason this works in Lua is because of dynamic typing- in C++ you could never really make it work. The closest you can get is the ternary operator, but it has srs limitations.

Comment: What are the limitations? All the other answers point to the ternary operator.

Answer (score -3):

Use `&&` in *C* or in *C++* for *and then* and use `||` for *or else*

Use the ternary `?:` for *conditional expressions*

Comment: -1 this question was about c++. there is no need to use "&&" instead of "and".