# meaning of a regexp if ($_ =~ /-\n/)

Tags: regex, perl

I am a beginner of perl scripting.
I know hyphen (-)  is used to specify the range.

But what if it is mentioned in the beginning of the expression?

Example:

```
if ($_ =~ /-\n/)
//do something
```

How to interpret the above code?

"if the parameter is equal to a range of newline" ?
(No, that is weird understanding :-/)

Please help.

Comment: `-` has a special meaning when it is between `[]`..if it is outside,it is just an `-`.

Comment: Sometimes a cigar is just a cigar.

Comment: @mob: May I know when a cigar is not just a cigar? ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means:

> If there is a hyphen immediately followed by a newline-character, no matter where this pair of characters is located inside the string.

Comment: Thank you very much to all for the answers. That clears my doubt. :)

Answer (score 7):

Outside of [] - means "-" as far as I know, it only indicates a range within a [] block.

Here is a more complete answer I found

[How to match hyphens with Regular Expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068629/how-to-match-hyphens-with-regular-expression/4068725#4068725)  (look at the second answer)

So the expression should match a - followed by a newline or line ending with -

Comment: The link is so useful. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 5):

The pattern will match hyphens `"-"` followed by a newline `\n`.

The hyphen is treated as a range operator inside character classes, as explained in [`perldoc perlrequick`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html):

> The special character `'-'` acts as a range operator within character
>   classes, so that the unwieldy `[0123456789]` and `[abc...xyz]` become
>   the svelte `[0-9]` and `[a-z]` :
>
> ```
> /item[0-9]/;  # matches 'item0' or ... or 'item9'
> /[0-9a-fA-F]/;  # matches a hexadecimal digit
> ```
>
> If `'-'` is the first or last character in a character class, it is
>   treated as an ordinary character.