# How to match a hyphen within a Qt regular expression

Tags: c++, regex, qt

Windows 7 SP1
MSVS 2010
Qt 4.8.4

I'm experimenting with the Qt  [Syntax Highlighter Example](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/richtext-syntaxhighlighter.html).

I have an application that needs to highlight words that start with a hyphen. So I modify the regular expression from this code fragment:

```
classFormat.setFontWeight(QFont::Bold);
classFormat.setForeground(Qt::darkMagenta);
rule.pattern = QRegExp("\\bQ[A-Za-z]+\\b");
rule.format = classFormat;
highlightingRules.append(rule);
```

which highlights words that start with Q. I change it to:

```
rule.pattern = QRegExp("\\b-[A-Za-z]+\\b");
```

and nothing happens.

I try

```
rule.pattern = QRegExp("\\b\\-[A-Za-z]+\\b");
```

Nothing.

Out of curiosity, I try

```
rule.pattern = QRegExp("\\b[-A-Za-z]+\\b");
```

If I start typing a hyphen, the hyphen is unhighlighted and every other alpha is highlighted. According to  [How to match hyphens with Regular Expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068629/how-to-match-hyphens-with-regular-expression) this should be kosher.

Question: How do I write the regular expression to highlight words starting with a hyphen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that a hyphen `-` is considered *not being part of a word*. This means, that the *word boundary assertion* `\b` will match between the hyphen and the actual word. In other words: *There is no word starting with a hyphen.*

To solve this issue, place the hyphen **before** `\b`, meaning you want to match "a hyphen, followed by a word consisting of letters". You can even remove the first `\b`, because `[a-zA-Z]+` is a word anyway:

```
rule.pattern = QRegExp("-[A-Za-z]+\\b");
```

Comment: Magic, thank you. Interesting. I thought word boundaries were defined by whitespace and any other character would be considered part of the word. When I used an underscore, it worked just fine. What is special about the hyphen?

Comment: Almost all special characters are considered word boundaries. Double-click on a word which is followed by a period, or quotation mark, or plus sign, ... It's the same. These characters aren't considered part of the word. However, we see underscores as part of names (e.g. variables in a source code for example), so it makes more sense to consider them as word characters. It's an arbitrary definition...