# bash escape ~ tilde

Tags: regex, bash

Does tilde character need to be escaped in bash script?

I have tried to escape it with \~ but it does not help. If I remove the ~ character, the code below works as expected.

```
            if ! [[ "$line" =~ ^[0-9a-zA-Z-~]+$ ]]; then
                    echo "skipping .. $line"
                    continue
            fi
```

How do I add the tilde character in the above expression?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't put ~ after -. Change the regexp to:

```
if ! [[ "$line" =~ ^[0-9a-zA-Z~-]+$ ]]; then
```

and you'll be fine.

Take a look to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4068725/465183) for more explanations why *hyphen* may be the last element of the class.

Comment: Bash is just confused because `-` is used to specify ranges in `[]`, except when it's first or last.

Comment: That's not only `bash`, see the link added in the post

Comment: It does make sense now. Thanks for the link