# Warning: preg_replace_callback() [function.preg-replace-callback]: Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 18 in

Tags: php

```
 function replaceQueryParams($string)
{
    $string = preg_replace_callback(
        '/\[\[([A-Za-z0-9_-\s]*)\]\]:(.*?):([10]*)/',
        array($this, 'getQueryParamsMatches'),
        $string
    );
    return $string;
}
```

When i tried to run the below code it throws error.

Comment: tel us the error u are getting ..

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape dashes when using them inside of character classes:

```
'/[[([A-Za-z0-9_\-\s])]]:(.?):([10]*)/'
```

Quoting from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4068725/697370) by Konrad Rudolph:

> The hyphen is usually a normal character in regular expressions. Only if it’s in a group expression and between two other characters does it take a special meaning.

The crux of the issue is that the regular expression is believing that this part of the character class: `_-\s` is denoting a character range (like as in `[A-Z]` or `[a-z]`) which is *invalid*, hence the error.

The regex engine does *not* treat the hyphen as part of a character range if it is included at either the beginning or end of the character class, so both of these would also work for you:

```
'/[[([A-Za-z0-9_\s-])]]:(.?):([10]*)/'
'/[[([-A-Za-z0-9_\s])]]:(.?):([10]*)/'
```