# Accept String Parameter in Yii2 Action

Tags: yii2

In my config file I've set the url rule like this :

```
<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>
```

And what happens is:-

```
controller/action/123 (work)
controller/action/hello (not work)
```

But it accepts only digit as the parameter.
What I want is that both digit and string should be accepted.

Please help!!!!

Comment: Do you meant the entire string after 123? You need to encode the string because the ' ' (spaces) will cause isses. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I mean that If action parameter is the string it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The d+ pattern matches numbers 0-9, so it is working as expected. Change the regex pattern to match strings. Try w+.

Change:

```
<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>
```

To:

```
<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>
```

Comment: I have changed d+ to w+ , but some string not work.
Ex: hello (work)
    hello world (not work)
    2013-12-11 (not work)
Sorry I'm not well in regex.

Comment: You need to decide what pattern you want to match and build an appropriate Regex.

Comment: How to match hypens (-) in regexp. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068629/how-to-match-hyphens-with-regular-expression