# Java matcher returning extra "." in output

Tags: java, regex

It's my part of java program for project.

```
String ops="";
String input="1+3-4+(7/8)+cos(sin(50)+2)/2+tan(90)*e^(5+26-4/1*2)";
input=input.replaceAll("cos", "c").replaceAll("sin", "s").replaceAll("tan", "t").replace("e", "2.718");
//System.out.println(input);
Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile("[+-/*()cst^]");
Matcher matcher= pattern.matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {ops+=matcher.group();}
System.out.println(ops);
```

Here I am just reading the input and giving output of **+,-,/,*,(,),c,s & t** present in it. The output `ops` should return `+-+(/)+c(s()+)/+t()*^(+-/*)` while it's returning `+-+(/)+c(s()+)/+t()*.^(+-/*)`.Help me understand the reason please.

Comment: From first glance it appears to be a result of subbing "2.718" in for "e", at least that is where the "." is coming from.

Comment: I know that , but my pattern doesn't have it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-` is used for a range, so `+-/` includes all characters between `+` and `/` (in the ascii table), i.e. `,-./`. To solve the issue you can place the `-` in first position:

```
Pattern.compile("[-+/*()cst^]");
```

Or you could also escape it. More about this: [How to match hyphens with Regular Expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068629/how-to-match-hyphens-with-regular-expression)

Comment: Alternatively `-` can be escaped by `\`. Obviously in java code `\` must be duplicated to pass java and regex escaping.

Comment: So that's the reason.Thanks.

Comment: @The_ehT yes it is in the character class section: `[a-zA-Z]       a through z or A through Z, inclusive (range)`