# how do I escape backslash in Grok custom pattern

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok, kibana-5

I have an input as

```
app\exceptions\SomeException
```

and pattern is

```
%{EXCEPTION_CLASS:exception}
```

and custom pattern as

```
{"EXCEPTION_CLASS" : "app\\\\exceptions\\\\SomeException"}
```

In Grok debugger(in Kibana), the output is as

```
{
  "exception": "app\\exceptions\\SomeException"
}
```

This is not what I was expecting.
First, using double backslash doesn't match the input.

```
{"EXCEPTION_CLASS" : "app\\exceptions\\SomeException"}
#This gives no output
```

Second, I got output with four backslash, but there were double backslash in it which what I expected was single backslash just like the input.

How does this work and how do I properly escape backslash in Grok pattern?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I escape backslash in logstash grok pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30304397/how-can-i-escape-backslash-in-logstash-grok-pattern)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your example. Following grok works for me with this input "\app\exection\somethingother"

```
grok{
    match => { "message" => "\\%{WORD:app}\\%{WORD:exception}\\%{WORD:other}" }
}
```

So \ for escaping \ works fine for me.

Comment: It works for me in logstash pipline. I don't understand the behavior in Grok debugger in Kibana.