# regular expression which allows square brackets

Tags: java, regex

Below is my code which allows  special characters, numbers, characters(upper and lower) .This program is working fine. My issue with square brackets.

```
public class MatchingSpecificCharacters {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String reg = "[A-Za-z0-9!$-~`?/@#%^*&()_+=<>.,';:|\" ]*";
        String line = "as[]d";

        System.out.println(line.matches(reg));


    }
}
```

### output

true

In the program, I have used [] brackets to enclose all the characters, numbers , special characters . I have not used extra square brackets to allow as special charters  but the program is allowing it. Can anyone tell me why it is allowing square brackets.Correct me If I am wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should escape the hyphen.

```
String reg = "[A-Za-z0-9!$\\-~`?/@#%^*&()_+=<>.,';:|\" ]*";
                           ^
```

or place it at the end

```
String reg = "[A-Za-z0-9!$~`?/@#%^*&()_+=<>.,';:|\" -]*";
```

This is what your regex matches (as instead of a hyphen, you defined a range from `$` till `~`):

[image]

Comment: The keyboard you have given, is not regular keyboard.Can give complete picture of the keyboard.(I don't know whether it is a keyboard). Please specify,  it will be helpful to others also.

Comment: It is not a keyboard, it is an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) which is a part of the [Unicode code point table](http://unicode.org/charts/). Regex is using Unicode code point table to resolve character ranges in [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a hyphen, you can either escape it or place it as the first or last character in the range:

`[-a-z]` or `[a-z-`]

Otherwise, `[A-Za-z ... $-~ ... \" ]` is trying to match all the given characters plus everything in between `$` and `~`, that you can visually see in [stribizhev's good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31921286/1983854).

See also [How to match hyphens with Regular Expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4068725/1983854):

> - `[-]` matches a hyphen.
> - `[abc-]` matches `a`, `b`, `c` or a hyphen.
> - `[-abc]` matches `a`, `b`, `c` or a hyphen.
> - `[ab-d]` matches `a`, `b`, `c` or `d` (*only here* the hyphen denotes a character range).

Comment: Never escape hyphen as it is not special character. When it is used in a range put it at beginning or end to avoid matching the range format.