# Remove anything before first hypen

Tags: regex, r

I have Data like this

```
0266-VN22.5P-AC
0292-VN22.6P-BC
0300-VN22.7P-CC
0316-VN22.8P-DC
```

I want to remove everything before first hypen and result should look like this

```
VN22.5P-AC
VN22.6P-BC
VN22.7P-CC
VN22.8P-DC
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Split on hyphen `-`, then paste back last 2?

Comment: `sub( "....-", "", c( "0266-VN22.5P-AC", "0292-VN22.6P-BC", "0300-VN22.7P-CC", "0316-VN22.8P-DC" ))`

Comment: with package `stringr` and if indeed the numbers at the beginning of string don't have the same number of digits, you can do `str_replace(x, str_extract(x, "\\d+"), str_pad(str_extract(x, "\\d+"), 6, pad = "0"))` to get what I think you want (if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: No Cath, digits vary from one to six... That's why I am splitting and making it 6 digit and adding it

Comment: then the solution in my comment should work, preferably assigning the result of `str_extract` to avoid the double call. (*just a remark, you should state that in the question, or make the number of digits vary in your example to make it representative and avoid answers that work on example data but not on the real ones*)

Comment: That was awesome Cath, It was good learning from you. Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
gsub("^[^\\-]+\\-", "", "0266-VN22.5P-AC")
```

Comment: Thank you, NJBurgo ... That is what I was looking for. May I know how to concate it again?

Comment: I don't know much about about regex, but why are you escaping the `-` sign? Is there anything wrong with `gsub("^[^-]+-", "", "0266-VN22.5P-AC")`? Anyway, +1.

Comment: `gsub` is vectorised, so will take in a concatenated set of inputs, returing the corrected values. `s <- c("0266-VN22.5P-AC", "0292-VN22.6P-BC", "0300-VN22.7P-CC")`, then `gsub("^[^\\-]+\\-", "", s)` will work

Comment: note that `sub("[^-]+-", "", "0266-VN22.5P-AC")` does the same... no need for `gsub` and a more complicated `regex`, `sub` will take only the first match into consideration, which is what OP wants

Comment: @RHertel, I am never sure about the `-` sign, it needs to be escaped inside `[..]` as in that case it would define a range. Therefore I always just escape it.

Comment: As it is the only thing in between brackets there, `-` doesn't need to be escaped in the first part. And definitely no need to escape it in the second part

Comment: I want to prefix the numbers with 0's so that I can make it six digits and then concatenate it again so that I can match with my original data. Hence I am extracting numbers and then making those as six digits with irrespective of any digit and then I would concatenate.

Comment: @Vinay you should ask the problem you really have instead of what you think is a part of it. I believe you can directly do what you need with `sprintf`

Comment: Also `gsub(".*?-(.*)", "\\1", "0266-VN22.5P-AC")`

Comment: @NJBurgo No need to escape it anywhere — see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4068725/1968

Answer (score 2):

Non-greedy search. The question mark is the magic:

```
sub(".*?-", "", x)
#[1] "VN22.5P-AC" "VN22.6P-BC" "VN22.7P-CC" "VN22.8P-DC"
```