# Hyphen and underscore not compatible in sed

Tags: regex, sed, character-class

I'm having trouble getting sed to recognize both hyphen and underscore in its pattern string.

Does anyone know why

```
[a-z|A-Z|0-9|\-|_]
```

in the following example works like

```
[a-z|A-Z|0-9|_]
```

?

```
$  cat /tmp/sed_undescore_hypen
lkjdaslf lkjlsadjfl dfpasdiuy service-type = service-1; jaldkfjlasdjflk address = address1; kldjfladsf
lkjdaslf lkjlsadjfl dfasdf  service-type = service_1; jaldkfjlasdjflk address = address1; kldjfladsf

$  sed 's/.*\(service-type = [a-z|A-Z|0-9|\-|_]*\);.*\(address = .*\);.*/\1    \2/g' /tmp/sed_undescore_hypen
lkjdaslf lkjlsadjfl dfpasdiuy service-type = service-1; jaldkfjlasdjflk address = address1; kldjfladsf
service-type = service_1    address = address1

$  sed 's/.*\(service-type = [a-z|A-Z|0-9|\-]*\);.*\(address = .*\);.*/\1    \2/g' /tmp/sed_undescore_hypen
service-type = service-1    address = address1
lkjdaslf lkjlsadjfl dfasdf  service-type = service_1; jaldkfjlasdjflk address = address1; kldjfladsf

$  sed 's/.*\(service-type = [a-z|A-Z|0-9|_]*\);.*\(address = .*\);.*/\1    \2/g' /tmp/sed_undescore_hypen
lkjdaslf lkjlsadjfl dfpasdiuy service-type = service-1; jaldkfjlasdjflk address = address1; kldjfladsf
service-type = service_1    address = address1
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As mentioned, you don't need anything to separate your ranges in a bracket expression. All that will do is adding `|` to the characters matched by the expression.

Then, to add a hyphen, you can put it as the first or last character in the expression:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_-]
```

And finally, ranges like `a-z` don't necessarily mean `abcd...xyz`, depending on your locale. You could use a POSIX character class instead:

```
[[:alnum:]_-]
```

Where `[:alnum:]` corresponds to all alphanumeric characters of your locale. In the `C` locale, it corresponds to `0-9A-Za-z`.

Comment: Hyphen *last*!  Aha.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `|` symbol in a [regex character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to separate the characters. Perhaps try something like this ...

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed 's/.*\(service-type = [a-z|A-Z|0-9|_-]*\);.*\(address = .*\);.*/\1    \2/g' sed_underscore_hypen.txt
service-type = service-1    address = address1
service-type = service_1    address = address1

pknga_000@miro MINGW64 ~/Documents
$ sed 's/.*\(service-type = [-a-z|A-Z|0-9|_]*\);.*\(address = .*\);.*/\1    \2/g' sed_underscore_hypen.txt
service-type = service-1    address = address1
service-type = service_1    address = address1
```

To match a hyphen in a character class, it must not be placed between two characters, otherwise it will be interpreted as a range operator. So to match a hyphen, place it at the beginning or end of the character class: and no escaping is necessary. See this answer for explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4068725

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wanted to replace a config setting that included a hyphen. Surrounding the setting in `.*` worked:

```
sed 's/.*some-service.*/some-service="new-value"/g' file
```

Also works when the config setting has an underscore.