# Regex match invalid pattern ios swift 4

Tags: swift, regex

**Swift 4.1**

I need to validate a password, but my last condition (regex) is who didnt match with the pattern, i got this regex to validate the last condition i need to verify if the password has special characters if has validate if the characters stay in this set (?=.*?[(!@$%^*()_-+{};:.,)]) if they are out of set i need to know and show alert, my code looks like this:

```
extension String{

    func isValidPassword(minCharacters : Int) -> Bool {
        let regexToMatch = "(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9]).{\(minCharacters),15}"
        let passwordPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", regexToMatch)

         guard passwordPredicate.evaluate(with: self) == true else {
             return false
         }

        guard self.hasSpecialCharacters() == true else {
            return true
        }


        //The problem is here!
        let regexToMatchCaracterSpecial = "(?=.*?[(!@$%^*()_+{};:.,)-])"
        let paswordCharacters = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", regexToMatchCaracterSpecial)
        return paswordCharacters.evaluate(with: self) == true
    }


    func hasSpecialCharacters() -> Bool {

        do {
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: ".*[^A-Za-z0-9].*", options: .caseInsensitive)
            if let _ = regex.firstMatch(in: self, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions.reportCompletion, range: NSMakeRange(0, self.count)) {
                return true
            }

        } catch {
            debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
            return false
        }

        return false
    }
}
```

The error is the next:

```
2018-09-19 17:03:15.353831-0500 mPaymentsAndLoyaly-Chedraui[47378:9327896] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Can't do regex matching, reason: Can't open pattern U_REGEX_INVALID_RANGE (string Alex1Ç, pattern (?=.*?[(!@$%^*()_-+{};:.,)]), case 0, canon 0)'
```

i Put the hyphen character but didnt evaluate the condition.

Comment: By seeing this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43438171/cant-do-regex-matching-in-swift-ios, it's probable that your regex is wrong.

Comment: Put the hyphen at the start/end of the character class.

Comment: can you explain where i need to put the hyphen ? Here? -(?=.*?[(!@$%^*()_-+{};:.,)])-