# RegEx matcher in Android

Tags: java, android, regex

I'm having trouble setting up a RegEx matcher in Android environment.

My String pattern:

```
private static final String INVALID_PATTERN = "/[^а-яa-z0-9\\s,!\\-_{\\}\\[\\];+]/ig";
```

Unescaped pattern (matches everything, but cyrillic and latin letters, numbers, space, comma, exclamation mark, minus, underscore, square brackets, semicolon and plus globally ignoring case; I consider those "legal"):

```
/[^а-яa-z0-9\s,!\-_\[\];+]/ig
```

My code:

```
public static ErrorType createStory(@NonNull String name){
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(INVALID_PATTERN).matcher(name);
    if(m.matches()){
        Log.e("Error", "Story name '" + name + "' contains illegal characters.");
        return ErrorType.ILLEGAL;
    }
    //...
}
```

This, however, neither throws any errors nor does work.

What I tried so far and didn't work (where string is a String variable):

- `string.matches(pattern)`
- `Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(string).matches()`

Comment: Should the string be valid if it only contains `а-яa-z0-9\s,!-_[];+`?

Comment: `/regex/flags` syntax is not supported in Java. Use `Pattern("regex",flags)` like `Pattern(".*foo",Pattern.DOTALL|Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Exactly. String is only considered invalid if it contains anything but those.

Comment: @Pshemo So instead of my pattern I should use `[^a-z0-9...]`? Not `/[^a-z0-9]/`?

Comment: Yes, those `/` are not needed here. BTW `matches()` tests if regex matches entire string (just like you would surround it with `^...$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
private static final String INVALID_PATTERN = "(?i)[а-яёa-z0-9\\s,!_{}\\[\\];+-]+";
```

and use it as

```
public static ErrorType createStory(@NonNull String name){
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(INVALID_PATTERN).matcher(name);
    if(!m.matches()){
        Log.e("Error", "Story name '" + name + "' contains illegal characters.");
        return ErrorType.ILLEGAL;
    }
    //...
}
```

**Explanation**:

- The `(?i)[а-яёa-z0-9\\s,!_{}\\[\\];+-]+` pattern matches the specified ranges and chars in a case-insensitive way (due to the embedded flag option `(?i)`), 1 or more occurrences
- Since the regex matches a *valid* string, `if (!m.matches())` is used to only show the error if the regex does not match the string
- As `.matches()` requires a full string match, no `^` and `$` anchors are necessary in the pattern
- In Android regex, regex delimiters are not used, and the way you pass regex options is either via `Pattern.<FLAG>` or via inline modifiers (as, e.g. `(?i)`)
- Judging by the range of Cyrillic letters, you want to match *Russian* letters, but **`а-я` does not include `ё`**, that is why I included it into the character class
- **Always put the hyphen at the start or end of the character class**, it will always be parsed as a literal `-` symbol. It is best practice, and will work in any regex flavor (if placed at the start - with any flavor I know).

If you want to use a *negative* approach, use

```
private static final String INVALID_PATTERN = "(?i)[^а-яёa-z0-9\\s,!_{}\\[\\];+-]";
```

and in the code, use `if (m.find())`

```
public static ErrorType createStory(@NonNull String name){
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(INVALID_PATTERN).matcher(name);
    if(m.find()){
        Log.e("Error", "Story name '" + name + "' contains illegal characters.");
        return ErrorType.ILLEGAL;
    }
    //...
}
```

Then, the error will be shown if the chars other than those defined in the negated character class are present in the string. `.find()` does not require a full string match, it allows partial matches.

Comment: Is Matcher/Pattern solution essentially the same as string.matches() but with `^...$`?

Comment: See my second part. You should declare the regex as a string, not as a regex literal (used in Ruby, JavaScript) and make sure you use appropriate methods: `Matcher.find()` searches for a match anywhere inside the string, and `Matcher.matches()` only tries to match the whole string against the pattern.

Comment: One more thing to note: `ё` does not belong to `а-я` range, I added it.

Comment: You should explain that using ``\\-`` is perfectly valid, but that *you* prefer to move it to the end so you can omit the escape characters, and that it is *important* that the `-` is at the end, and why that is so.

Comment: Whenever one wants to use a literal `-` inside a character class, it is best practice to use it at the start or end of the character class. Here is [an illustration](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4068725/3832970).

Comment: The advantage of the negative `find()` over the positive `matches()`, is that `find()` will tell you the location and value of the offending character, while `matches()` won't.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I meant that you should *edit* the answer and explain, without silently making the change, especially because it's potentially dangerous if someone who doesn't know about `-` adds extra characters to the end of the character class.