# Why '[,-\\]' match '46', 'X', 'A',

Tags: r, regex

I try to split a string using `strsplit(str, '[,-\\+]')`, which means any `',', '-' or '+'` could be a delimiter. However, I found this pattern seems to also match numbers and capital letters.
Try

- `grep('[,-\\]', 'X'), returns 1`
- `grep('[,-\\]', '46'), returns 1`
- `grep('[,-\\]', '-'), returns 1`
- `grep('[,-\\]', ','), returns 1`

It seems to be `'[,-\\]'` matching all numbers, capital letters, `','` and `'-'`.

I just don't get why this is the case.

Thank you for any input

Comment: If I change the order of the pattern like '[\\+,-]', then this only matches '+', ',' and '-'. I am confused

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to match hyphens with Regular Expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068629/how-to-match-hyphens-with-regular-expression)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use

```
strsplit(str, '[,+-]')
```

to split on `,` `+` or `-`. If you need to add `\` to split on, use `'[,\\+-]'` with the *default* TRE regex engine.

When `-` is at the end (or at the start, too) of the bracket expression, it is parsed as a literal hyphen. In your case, it is treated as a range operator and `'[,-\\]'` matches a range of chars between `,` and `\`:

[image]

Note that you are using a TRE regex flavor here (since no `perl=TRUE` is specified), thus, the double backslash is treated as a literal backslash in the regex pattern. `"[,-\\]"` pattern would be invalid if you used a PCRE regex engine to parse the pattern, you would need to define a backslash with 4 backslashes in the string literal.