# regex expression for alpha numeric and some special characters

Tags: regex, angular, typescript

I need a regex expression for pattern validation that should allow only alphanumeric words and some special characters that are `!@#$%^&*()-_`

I tried that expression but it didn't work

```
Validators.pattern("^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^*-_&()\\\"]*$")
```

Comment: On what format it did not work? Can provide sample string?

Comment: it allows plus "+" and dot "." and also other special characters that i not mentioned

Comment: Just check my answer. It will not allow other than provided spacial characters.

Comment: Please try this: `^[\w!@#$%^\-_&()\\]*$` where `\w` stands for alphanumeric chars

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to match hyphens with Regular Expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068629/how-to-match-hyphens-with-regular-expression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the `*-_` inside your character set. This is treated as a range of **all** the characters from `*` to `_` i.e. `*`, `+`, `,` ... `]`, `^`, `_` (I've left out the rest of the characters for brevity). You need to either put the `-` at the beginning or end of the set, or escape it within the set e.g.

```
Validators.pattern("^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^*_&()\\\"-]*$")
```