# Java minus sign and hypen difference in regex

Tags: java, regex, intellij-idea, character-encoding, nsregularexpression

I am checking file names with a regex.

File names can be format of

> customer name - company name

I am using this regex:

```
private static final Pattern fileRegex = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.\\s\\,\\[\\]()\\{\\}]+$");
```

But hypen sign (minus sign) is not working and it is acting like a dash. 
I am not sure maybe it is because of IntelliJ idea settings.
how can I add minus sign to this regex?

For example this format must be valid:

> test - test1 − test2

In here first one is just simple dash and the second one is minus sign.

Comment: Just add a hyphen - in the regular expression without wild cards. It will accept a plain and simple hyphen

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4069678/3832970), you may either add all "dashes" you want to the character class, or just use `\p{Pd}` to match all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Well, they are different unicode symbols after all

code points are different: 45 for dash and 8722 for minus

You have to replace \- with [\-\−]

Answer (score 0):

Add the minus sign (`\u2212`) to your character set:

```
private static final Pattern fileRegex = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\u2212\\.\\s\\,\\[\\]()\\{\\}]+$");
```