# Matching pattern using Regular expression in Python and output to CSV file

Tags: python-3.x, csv, python-re

Trying to find pattern from a given .txt file and write the found match to Output CSV.

Request to assist on this

```
`def output():
    filtered_messages = ['Current date & time ']
    fieldnames = ['currenttime', 'output']
    with open("test1.txt", "r") as f:
        count = 0
        while True:
            count = count +1
            line = f.readline()
            with open(line.rstrip("\n"), "r") as j:
                with open('output.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
                    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames)
                    writer.writerow(dict((fn,fn) for fn in fieldnames))
                    a = 0
                    while True:
                        a = a + 1
                        lines = j.readlines()
                        match = re.search(r'\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}_\d{2}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}', lines)
                        if match is not None in filtered_messages:
                            writer.writerow(match.groupdict())


output()`
```

Error:

```
   match = re.search(str(r'\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}_\d{2}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}'), lines)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/re.py", line 200, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

content of the files will contain a line shown below

sample test1.txt

Current date & time : 2023-07-22_23-02-09

Comment: `.readlines()` returns a `list`, but the input parameter for `re.search` needs to be an individual string. So you could map the strings within the list, e.g. using a list comprehension, like: `[re.search(r'\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}_\d{2}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}', line) for line in lines]`. Or, you could join `lines` (`'\n'.join(lines)`) and feed that as the input to `re.search`.

Answer (score 0):

I see some confusion in the way you've written your code up this point and I'd like to make some suggestions that might help.

### Collect your matches in one place, first

To avoid such deeply nested code/logic I recommend iterating the lines of the input file and finding and saving matches as a first step:

```py
import re

date_pattern = r"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}_\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}"
matches: list[re.Match[str]] = []

with open("input.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        m = re.search(date_pattern, line)
        if m is not None:
            matches.append(m)
```

Also, you don't need to escape the hyphens in the regex:  The following two regexes are equivalent:

```py
r"\d{4}-\d{2}"
r"\d{4}\-\d{2}"
```

For a good look at hyphens in regexes, I recommend checking out this [short answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4068725/246801).

I also like type hints, so I've type-hinted my matches list.

### Review your matches (just to debug, understand what the code does)

I mocked up some input text:

```
Foo
Bar
Current date & time : 2023-07-22_23-02-09
Baz
2012-12-12_13-13-13
```

To see my matches after running the previous code:

```py
for m in matches:
    print(f"match={m}; match.group()={m.group()}")

# m=<re.Match object; span=(22, 41), match='2023-07-22_23-02-09'>; m.group()=2023-07-22_23-02-09
# m=<re.Match object; span=( 0, 19), match='2012-12-12_13-13-13'>; m.group()=2012-12-12_13-13-13
```

You tried using [`Match.groupdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.groupdict), which only works if your regex has *named* subgroups.  As is, your regex has no subgroups (so no named subgroups).  Instead, you can use `Match.group()` to get the matched text.

### Create your CSV based on matches

Since you don't need (cannot use) groupdict, I don't see the need for csv.DictWriter.

I think the list-based writer will easily give you your desired result (which I actually don't know, but think I have a good-enough idea of):

```py
import csv

with open("output1.csv", "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["currenttime", "output"])
    for m in matches:
        writer.writerow([m.group(), "???"])
```

I think you can just write the header row directly, then use `m.group()` to create the following rows.  That output looks like:

```
| currenttime         | output |
|---------------------|--------|
| 2023-07-22_23-02-09 | ???    |
| 2012-12-12_13-13-13 | ???    |
```

I also saw you explicitly making counting variables, `count` and `a`.  For either the read or write steps, I recommend using Python's `enumerate()` built-in, maybe something like:

```py
# store the match and the line (int) it was found on
matched_lines: list[tuple[int, re.Match[str]]] = []

with open("input.txt") as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f, start=1):
        line = re.search(date_pattern, line)
        if line is not None:
            matched_lines.append((i, line))


with open("output2.csv", "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["Original line", "Current time"])
    for ml in matched_lines:
        writer.writerow([ml[0], ml[1].group()])
```

```
| Original line | Current time        |
|---------------|---------------------|
| 3             | 2023-07-22_23-02-09 |
| 5             | 2012-12-12_13-13-13 |
```

Comment: @Srinivas, if this answer solves the stated problem, please accept it by clicking the checkmark at the top left of the answer. And, you’re welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `readlines()` and iterate through each line,

```
def output():
filtered_messages = ['Current date & time']
fieldnames = ['currenttime', 'output']
with open("test1.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
with open('output.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writerow(dict((fn,fn) for fn in fieldnames))
    for line in lines:
        match = re.search(r'\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}_\d{2}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}', line)
        if filtered_messages[0] in line:
            writer.writerow({'currenttime':match.group(),'output':'someValue'})
output()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).